# Low distortion embeddings (reference request)

Tags: reference-request, metric-spaces

I read about the [Johnson Lindenstrauss Lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Johnson%E2%80%93Lindenstrauss_lemma).
I googled and found that low distortion embeddings is a live subject, but it seems that many interesting results are already known.

Is there a book on the subject? (there is one chapter in Lectures on Discrete Geometry / Matousek).

What papers cover the basic results and by which order should they be read?

*Note*: It is acceptable for me to read outdated results if they can serve a didactic purpose.

Comment: Nothing really helpful to your query, but here's how [Bill Johnson](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/9218/probabilistic-proofs-of-analytic-facts/10181#10181) described the lemma on MO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend *Geometry of Cuts and Metrics* by Deza and Laurent, which is [available from Deza's page](http://www.liga.ens.fr/~deza/BOOK1/cutbook.pdf). Other notable sources are:

- [Embeddings and extensions in analysis](http://books.google.com/books/about/Embeddings_and_extensions_in_analysis.html?id=YvTuAAAAMAAJ) by Wells and Williams: a short and accessible book which focuses on isometric embeddings. Unfortunately, it was out of print last time I checked.
- [Asymptotic theory of finite dimensional normed spaces](http://books.google.com/books/about/Asymptotic_Theory_of_Finite_Dimensional.html?id=tTnvAAAAMAAJ) by Milman and Schechtman -- because it helps to understand the geometry of normed spaces before trying to embed things into them.
- [Geometric nonlinear functional analysis](http://books.google.com/books?id=lXZ95EKwjYUC) by  Benyamini and Lindenstrauss is very much related but has a different emphasis.
- [Everything written by Assaf Naor](http://www.cims.nyu.edu/~naor/).